# How to get a Sitecore Items Parent Path

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

We are using the weblog module.

So you have a

```
Blog template 
    -- Folders
       -- Entry
```

We are trying to get the Item path for the Blog Item itself to set as a datasource for a link Item

Can I get the grandparent's Item path info from the Entry object using sitecore query or something else

Answer (score 2):

Via property traversal:

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Parent.Parent
```

Via query:

```
./ancestor::*[@@templatename='Blog template']
```

Am I over simplifying a response to your question?

Comment: `./ancestor::*[@@templatename='Blog template']` sort of work to get the entire item... what if I just wanted the item path of the item via query?

Comment: Hmm...don't think it's possible to only get a field from a query.